# Firebase 3 - Deleting an account

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement a way to my user to delete an account.

I know I can use this to delete an account:

```
try {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.delete().then( () => {

         this.storage.clear();
         (<any>window).location = 'index.html';
     }, (error) => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
     });
 }catch (err) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
 }
```

But I am always getting an error saying that some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account require that the user has recently signed in (I've just logged in 1 minute ago).

And I don't want to force the user to logout all the time.

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you try calling [`reauthenticate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticate)  right before deleting the user?

Comment: I can try, I just need to get the credential (and I don't know how), but anyway. Why should I reauthenticate when I've just logged in??